# How do I include zeros in a count(column)?

Tags: oracle-11g

I am attempting to build a report for a client. I need a display of all the values in Tab1, Col1 (a validation table), a count of each time that occurred, and a percentage of the total. Here's what I'm looking for:

```
Number of records       Type        Percentage of total
2                       A           2
3                       B           3
0                       C           0
```

I have the basic query worked out, I just don't know how to include the zero count! Here's what I have so far:

```
select count(b.Col1) "Number of Records",
a.col2 "Type",
to_char(round(ratio_to_report(count(a.Col1)) over()*100)) || '%' as "Percantage of Total"
from Tab1 a,
Tab2 b
where Tab2.Col1 = Tab1.Col1(+)
group by a.Col1;
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Attempting this:

```
select count(b.Col1) "Number of Records", 
a.col2 "Type",
to_char(round(ratio_to_report(count(b.Col1)) over()*100)) || '%' as "Percantage of Total"
from Tab2 b
left join Tab1 a on tab2.col1 = tab1.col1 -- or (from tab2 left join tab1) if that is what's intended
group by a.Col1;
```

Gave me the same results as my query.

This:

```
select COALESCE(count(b.Col1), 0) AS "Number of Records", 
a.col2 "Type",
to_char(round(ratio_to_report(count(b.Col1)) over()*100)) || '%' as "Percantage of Total"
from Tab1 a
left join Tab2 b on tab1.col1 = tab2.col1
group by a.Col1;
```

Also gives me the same results.

EDIT 2:

Table A columns: ID, Code, Description

Table B Columns: ID, RecordNumber, TableA_ID

Table B is a "master" and Table A is one of the many "details". Basically I need a count of TableA instances in TableB.. including the zeros.

Query that gave me my desired results:

```
select coalesce(count(b.TabA_id),0) as "num records",
a.desc "type",
to_char(round(ratio_to_report(count(b.TabA_id)) over()*100)) || '%' as "Percentage of Total"
from TabB b
right join TabA a on b.TabA_id = a.id
group by  b.TabA_id, a.id
order by a.desc;
```

Comment: You'll want to change both count() records to table b...

Comment: Oh my, I haven't seen the ancient syntax `(+)` for a long time. You should really use the "new" outer `join` syntax ("new" as in 23 years new.)

Comment: @ypercube Yeah, I know. Just trying to keep the queries looking the same in our reports.

Comment: For more assistance you'll need to provide us with the table definitions for tab1 and tab2..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much information you provide, so this is only a guess.

Your WHERE clause `Tab2.Col1 = Tab1.Col1(+)` may be backward, with regard to the (+) ... I would recommend switching it to a LEFT JOIN regardless, just to make it more readable..

```
select
  count(b.Col1) "Number of Records", --- CHANGED a.Col1 to b.Col1
  a.col2 "Type",
  to_char(round(ratio_to_report(count(b.Col1)) over()*100)) || '%' as "Percantage of Total"
from Tab1 a
left join Tab2 b on tab1.col1 = tab2.col1 -- or (from tab2 left join tab1) if that is what's intended
group by a.Col1;
```

If you are still not getting the 0 counts, then you should try a coalesce statement.

```
select
  COALESCE(count(b.Col1), 0) AS "Number of Records", --- COALESCE HERE .. CHANGED a.Col1 to b.Col1
  a.col2 "Type",
  to_char(round(ratio_to_report(count(b.Col1)) over()*100)) || '%' as "Percantage of Total"
from Tab1 a
left join Tab2 b on tab1.col1 = tab2.col1
group by a.Col1;
```

You are not referencing table b anywhere in your sql, though - please explain why you need to join to it if you're not going to be using its data?

Comment: table a is a validation table where I get the list. Table b is the actual number of records. Should I be counting table b instead of table a?

Comment: Yes. Counting a instead of b may sometimes be the same .. but it will not work if b is NULL (which in this case it will be when you SHOULD have a 0)  My first SQL should do that.  Assuming I understand what you mean correctly.

Comment: And it was a `right join` I needed to get the results. Maybe I had the join condition in the wrong order... but  yay for guess and check.

Comment: You need either `tab1 left join tab2` or `tab2 right join tab1`. Most people prefer to use only left joins.