# Adding counts inside a COALESCE

Tags: join, oracle-10g, aggregate

So I have a continuation of [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93152/how-do-i-include-zeros-in-a-countcolumn) question. New requirements have thrown in a third table.

So here's the breakdown of how the tables relate:

```
TabA(TabA_id, desc)
TabB(TabB_id, TabA_id)
TabC(TabC_id, TabA_id)
```

I need a count of each time a TabA desc occurs in both TabB and TabC, and I only need the records from TabC that have a TabA_id.

This is the query that is getting me close (sort of):

```
select  COALESCE(count(b.TabC_id) + count(c.TabC_id), 0) as "Number of Records",
a.desc as "Type",
to_char(round(ratio_to_report(count(b.TabC_id) + count(c.TabC_id)) over()*100)) || '%' as "Percentage of Total" 
from TabA a
left join TabB on a.TabA_id = TabB.TabA_id,
TabB b
left join TabC on b.TabC id = TabC.TabC_id,
TabC c
right join TabA on c.TabA_id = TabA.TabA_id
where c.TabA_id is not null
group by b.TabC_id, c.TabC_id, a.desc 
order by a.desc asc;
```

Hope this makes some sense. Looking forward to comments for clarification.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, do you need a count or the records (rows) from tabC?

Comment: Sorry, the alias is a bit misleading. I need a count from tabC and tabB any time an instance of tabA occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm giving it a shot, still not sure if I got it:

```
select 100.0*(count(b.taba_id) + count(c.taba_id)) 
     / (( select count(1) from b) + (select count(1) from c)) 
from taba as a
left join tabb as b 
    on a.id = b.id 
left join tabc as c
    on a.id = c.id
```

Some thoughts, count will newer return null so coalesce is pointless. If the above is correct it is possible to use window function (as I think you have tried to do), to replace the total count's

Comment: Yeah, I just found out about the count piece. I was (most likely) restricting my original query too far and not getting them. I'll check this out, thanks!

Comment: You were leading me in the right direction, but not quite there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what wound up working for me:

```
select 
    a.desc, 
    count(union_all.TabA_id) as "Count of A",
    to_char(round(ratio_to_report(count(union_all.TabA_id)) over()*100))
      || '%' as "Percentage of Total"
from 
    TabA a
  left join 
    (
      select TabA_id from TabC
      union all
      select TabA_id from TabB
    ) 
    union_all
      on union_all.TabA_id = a.TabA_id
group by 
    a.desc
order by 
    a.desc;
```

Thanks @Lennart for the help!

Edited per @ypercube's keen eye.

Comment: Indeed, you are correct. Caught another one too..

Comment: Took the liberty of reformatting (and converting that `right` join to `left`). I hope you don't mind.